# Am I getting "guild is not defined" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'freeze',
    description: 'Gives everyone time to chill out',
    execute(message, args) {
        if (message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Moderator")) {

            guild.updateOverwrite(guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
            message.reply("Frozen!");

        } else {
            message.reply('Invalid Permissions bucko!');
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `guild.updateOverwrite()` since `guild` is not defined.
You can fix that by using: `message.guild.updateOverwrite()`.